# I want to put my words into a formula/algorithm but I lack the mathematical fortitude

Tags: algorithms

This should be pretty simple.  Here is what I want to put into a formula/algorithm:

> Divide the size of every object of an array by the number of times that object has been accessed in the last *n* seconds and **discarding the highest quotient.** (You can probably ignore the bold part)

I can program this just fine, but I am going to be showing it to a Mathematician (one of my professors) and I would like to impress him a bit.  If the description of what I want is not clear and an example in code would help let me know and I'll whip something up real quick.

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus do you know how to write what I want in a formula?  The part I don't know how to do is representing the array (I assume I would use a set) in mathematical terms and showing in the formula that I want to "loop" through all items in the set.

Comment: I agree with Yuval here; there's no reason to use any fancy math notation because the words you have currently are already very clear. Adding any symbols would unnecessarily complicate the algorithm. (And anyway, I don't think that there is any standard notation for what you want. Probably the best you can do is just write pseudocode for the algorithm, but that's not particularly _mathy_.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sizes of the objects form a vector $\vec{s}$. The access statistics form a vector $\vec{a}$. The quotients form a vector $\vec{q}$ defined by $$q_i = n_i/a_i.$$ This is your array division. The "mathy" notation is $q_i$ for the C "q[i]".

Now you want to take your array and ignore the maximum, so let $$p = \mathrm{argmax}_i q_i,$$ and then you want to ignore coordinate $p$.

But I think your professor also understands English.

Comment: Point taken, I will stick with the English version and simply augment it with what I know (code).